# how change QGroupBox::title property if QGroupBox is checked?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

How I can use different Qss for QGroupBox::title if QGroupBox is checked?
for example:

```
QGroupBox::title{ /*if QGroupBox:checked*/
 border-bottom:2px solid red;
}

QGroupBox::title{ /*if QGroupBox:unchecked*/
 border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [pseudo states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states). In your case `:checked`. I assume it must look like this `QGroupBox:checked::title{/*whatever*/}`, but not 100% sure

Comment: I test it, but not work

Comment: I was thinking about it for a while and I am not sure that Qt Style Sheets allows to customize something depending on other component's property. Not by default at least. The workaround I saw was to use [customization with dynamic properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties). I tried it like this `QGroupBox[checked=\"true\"]::title`, but it doesn't seem to work dynamically :(